# SwipeRefreshLayout's onRefreshListener doesn't work on databinding mvvm android

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-databinding, swiperefreshlayout, android-mvvm

I want to refresh a list of elements by using MVVM and data binding but SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't work on XML layout.

BaseViewModel.java

```java
public class BaseViewModel<N> extends ViewModel {
    private final DataManager mDataManager;

    private final ObservableBoolean mIsLoading = new ObservableBoolean(false);

    private final SchedulerProvider mSchedulerProvider;

    private CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable;

    private WeakReference<N> mNavigator;

    public BaseViewModel(DataManager dataManager,
                         SchedulerProvider schedulerProvider) {
        this.mDataManager = dataManager;
        this.mSchedulerProvider = schedulerProvider;
        this.mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        mCompositeDisposable.dispose();
        super.onCleared();
    }

    public CompositeDisposable getCompositeDisposable() {
        return mCompositeDisposable;
    }

    public DataManager getDataManager() {
        return mDataManager;
    }

    public ObservableBoolean getIsLoading() {
        return mIsLoading;
    }

    public void setIsLoading(boolean isLoading) {
        mIsLoading.set(isLoading);
    }

    public N getNavigator() {
        return mNavigator.get();
    }

    public void setNavigator(N navigator) {
        this.mNavigator = new WeakReference<>(navigator);
    }

    public SchedulerProvider getSchedulerProvider() {
        return mSchedulerProvider;
    }
}
```

HomeViewModel.java

```java
public class HomeViewModel extends BaseViewModel<HomeNavigator> {
    private  MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HeartRateResultsModel>> heartRateResultsLiveData;

    public HomeViewModel(DataManager dataManager, SchedulerProvider schedulerProvider) {
        super(dataManager, schedulerProvider);
        heartRateResultsLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        fetchRepos();
    }
    public void fetchRepos() {
        setIsLoading(true);
        getCompositeDisposable().add(getDataManager()
                .getHeartRateResults()
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribe(heartRateResultsModels -> {
                    heartRateResultsLiveData.setValue(heartRateResultsModels);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                }, throwable -> {
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    getNavigator().handleError(throwable);
                }));
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<HeartRateResultsModel>> getHeartRateResultsLiveData() {
        return heartRateResultsLiveData;
    }

    public void onRefresh(){
        Log.d("refresh","oy");
        fetchRepos();
    }
}
```

fragment_home.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="ir.basamadazmanovin.heartrate.ui.main.home.HomeViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:onRefreshListener="@{()-> viewModel.onRefresh()}"
        app:refreshing="@{viewModel.isLoading}">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/fragment_home_toolbar"
                style="@style/Toolbar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:subtitleTextColor="@color/material_white"
                app:title="@string/app_name"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/material_white" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/fragment_home_recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_home_toolbar"
                app:spanCount="3" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</layout>
```

app:onRefreshListener="@{()-> viewModel.onRefresh()}"

this is where I added the code. also 
app:refreshing="@{viewModel.isLoading}"
work properly but I am seeking for a listener which can detect what the user wants. in Addition, onRefresh() didn't get called when the user refresh

Comment: why refresh swipe layout, did `fetchRepos()` get called ?

Comment: @JohnJoe , i want to let user to refresh and get new data. onRefresh() didn't get called

Comment: Facing the same issue.Did you find a solution @omid?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refresh the layout by implementing `setOnRefreshListener` inside the activity and not the view model. Inside the implementation part, you can call `fetchRepos()` using view model, such as : `homeViewModel!!.fetchRepos()`